# use c# to convert an address in csv file in coordinate gps and update this csv file for include the latitude and the longitude

Tags: c#, google-maps, csv, gps

it's my first post and I have a problem in my code.

I want to use data of a csv file and extract the address in c# and then, return the latitude and the longitude in this csv file.

Here is my csv file:

```
id;address;latitude;longitude;
01;paris;;
02;londres;;
04;madrid;;
05;berlin;;
```

And my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 

        {
            string line;

            CSV csv = new CSV();

            StreamReader reader =  new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\louis\Documents\coordonnee_gps\donnee.csv");
            var request = new GeocodingRequest();

            var adresse = "";
            string[] row = new string[5];
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                if (adresse != null)
                {
                    request.Address = adresse;
                    request.Sensor = false;
                    var response = new GeocodingService().GetResponse(request);
                    var result = response.Results.First();
                    row[2] = "latitude" + result.Geometry.Location.Latitude;
                    row[3] = "longitude" + result.Geometry.Location.Longitude;
                }
            }

            csv.Save(new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\louis\Documents\coordonnee_gps\donnee.csv"));
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: when I run this code, not any update in my csv file and I have this error: Une exception non gérée du type 'System.InvalidOperationException' s'est produite dans System.Core.dll

Answer (score 0):

Close `StreamReader` first to reopen file for writing:

Add `reader.close();` before `csv.Save`

Comment: I managed to update the csv file without reader.close (), but I defined before the address and not here to pick up in the original csv file